# Canceling user input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

Let's say I have this bit of code in java:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

Long time = System.nanoTime() + 10000000000L; //10 seconds in the future
String input = s.nextLine();
//What to do from here?

System.out.println("Timed out");
```

How could I cancel the user input if they haven't inputted anything yet and the current time is greater than `time`? Is there any way to enable the user to input something but also run code during that time? `nextLine()` seems to pause the execution until the user does input something.

Answer (score 0):

many 'block until something happens' methods (such as `java.lang.Thread`'s `wait` method) have an overloaded variant where you can specify a timeout. However, most I/O methods (such as scanner's `nextLine`, or inputstream's `read`) do not.

The specification of these types indicates that whether they are interruptable or not is intentionally not defined; java wants to run on as many platforms as possible, and the lowest common denominator is 'no, not interruptable', which is why it is specified that way.

However, on most platforms, yes, you can interrupt it.

Thus, the solution:

Start a second thread, hand it a reference to your thread, and tell it to interrupt this thread after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

A thread that is interrupted just 'raises the interrupt flag', nothing more (you can check with `if (Thread.interrupted()) ...;` if you like, which also clears this flag. However, various methods built into java will immediately exit if you call them whilst that flag is raised, and will abort in place if you raise the flag while they are blocking.

Any method that is declared to throw `InterruptedException`, like `Thread.sleep`, is *guaranteed* to have this behaviour. Any other blocking method may or may not (back to that whole 'common denominator of all platforms java runs on' thing). In other words, as you don't quite know where your code is going to be, you need to deal with various scenarios. What if the interrupt occurs as you're waiting for input (most likely, readLine ends by throwing something that you can catch), what if it occurs right after (that flag would be up; you'd need to clear it at some point), and how do you 'cancel the cancel' - if the user does type, you want that ticking timebomb thread to end itself. You can do that by just setting a variable that the timebomb thread checks, even if it only checks it after time's up (Time's up! Oh, the thread I'm supposed to interrupt has told me sometime whilst I was waiting for the timeout that it is no longer needed so I shall just end now).

All rather complicated. There may be some library out there to make this a lot simpler for you, but I am not personally aware of one.

```java
public class InterruptMeThread extends Thread {
    private final Thread interruptMe;
    private final long millis;
    private volatile boolean nevermind;

    public InterruptMeThread(Thread interruptMe, long millis) {
        this.interruptMe = interruptMe;
        this.millis = millis;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Who interrupts the interruptors? Let's assume this means
            // My interruption services are no longer desired and exit.
            return;
        }

        if (!nevermind) interruptMe.interrupt();
    }

    public void nevermind() {
        this.nevermind = true;
        Thread.interrupted(); // clear the flag if it is raised.
    }
}
```

And in use:

```java
InterruptMeThread imt = new InterruptMeThread(Thread.currentThread(), 10000);
imt.start();
try {
    reader.nextLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // You'd have to test what kind of exception falls out of interrupted...
    // But something will
    // For now, to debug it so we can see it...
    throw new RuntimeException(e); // or just let it bubble up, either way works.
}
imt.nevermind();
```

Comment: I don't understand most of what you said, but I'll try it.

Comment: Part of the 'point' of my answer is that it is quite complicated and not even guranteed to work on all possible platforms. For example, I have no idea if you are just using notepad or programming this in intellij or eclipse, but java IDEs like intellij or eclipse have their own windowed consoles, and often that interrrupt thing just -does not work-, -at all- in those, and cannot be made to work. How badly do you need this?

Comment: Not badly. I was trying to make something on a website we use at school, but imo that site is trash so I stopped using it for anything practical.